# Multiple Jersey Applications with same path for root resource

Tags: spring, jersey, jax-rs

I recently ran into a situation where I wanted two separate Jersey applications in a single Spring MVC web app. I created two separate servlets that map to different URIs, and two separate root resource classes that have the same path.

Application 1 Servlet:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JerseyServlet1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>public.api.rest.Application1</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JerseyServlet1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Application 2 Servlet:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JerseyServlet2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>private.api.rest.Application2</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JerseyServlet2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/internal/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Application 1:

```
package public.api.rest;

public class Application1 extends PackagesResourceConfig {
    public Application1(){
        super(Application1.class.getPackage().getName());
    }
}
```

Application 2:

```
package private.api.rest;

public class Application2 extends PackagesResourceConfig {
    public Application2(){
        super(Application2.class.getPackage().getName());
    }
}
```

Application 1 Root Resource:

```
package public.api.rest;

@Path("release-1")
@Component
@Scope("request")
public class App1Root{
    //resource methods
}
```

Application 2 Root Resource:

```
package private.api.rest;

@Path("release-1")
@Component
@Scope("request")
public class App2Root{
    //resource methods
}
```

Jersey exception thrown during application initialization:

```
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Conflicting URI templates. The URI template /release-1 for root resource class private.api.rest.App2Root and the URI template /release-1 transform to the same regular expression /release-1(/.*)?
```

Since these are two separate Applications and two separate servlets, I was expecting this to work. Is this not possible in Jersey or is there a different approach?

Comment: How do your application classes look like? I mean public.api.rest.Application1 and public.api.rest.Application2. Can you post that code?

Comment: Just edited the post to add the code for App1Root and App2Root

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple issues:

1. Don't use the same class for application and for a resource. Resources are instantiated per-request. That means the constructor should be lightweight. You don't want to instantiate PackagesResourceConfig for every request that comes. I.e. use a separate class for application and a separate one for a resource.
2. All your code resides in one package and you are using package scanning. What this means is, that when App1Root get's instantiated by the servlet, it does the package scanning (because you inherit from PackagesResourceConfig) of private.api.rest package (and all subpackages), finds both App1Root and App2Root annotated with the same @Path and fails.

You can fix this by splitting the resources and apps and putting resources for app1 into a different package than app2. E.g. the following should work:

Application1:

```
package private.api.rest;

public class App1Root  extends PackagesResourceConfig {
    public App1Root(){
        super("private.api.rest.app1");
    }
}
```

Application2:

```
package private.api.rest;

public class App2Root  extends PackagesResourceConfig {
    public App2Root(){
        super("private.api.rest.app2");
    }
}
```

Resource class 1:

```
package public.api.rest.app1;

@Path("release-1")
@Component
@Scope("request")
public class App1Root {
    // resource methods here
}
```

Resource class 2:

```
package public.api.rest.app2;

@Path("release-1")
@Component
@Scope("request")
public class App1Root {
    // resource methods here
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help. I have edited my post to show the latest code.

Comment: Did you see bullet 2) in my response? Again, you are using package scanning feature, which finds all resources in a given package. If you want to use that and have distinct resources in your apps, you have to use different packages for those resources.

Comment: Yes. They are in two separate packages though: "private.api.rest" and "public.api.rest" - shouldn't that be sufficient?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that. I tried your sample - used different package names, since public.... and private... are not valid. Worked for me, but haven't tried with SpringServlet - just the regular one. Anyway, have you cleaned your project after making the packaging changes? If you don't do clean, the old class files are still around, which would explain the error. Make sure you do clean build.

Comment: You are right. It works when it's not a SpringServlet. Is there a way to get it work with the SpringServlet? We want to use request level spring security for authorization

Comment: Looks like a bug in the SpringServlet implementation. We need to investigate. Would you mind filing an issue here: http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY? That way you can track the progress.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/contribs/jersey-spring/com/sun/jersey/spi/spring/container/servlet/package-summary.html

Comment: Since you are not using the contextConfigLocation parameter, it is using the default application context config for both servlets. Also the doc says: "Any root resource classes or provider classes declared by Spring (in the XML configuration or by auto-wiring) will be automatically registered." You need to make sure these resources are  not picked up automatically by Spring for both servlets. I am not familiar with spring, so not sure if you have to remove the @Component annotation or if you can make it work by the way of tweaking the config and supplying a different config to each servlet.

Comment: Somehow this is more related to Spring than Jersey. The resources used spring beans injected with @Autowired annotation. When I switched that to one of our SpringUtil.getBean(type) to get an instance, the issue disappeared.